# Qt Creator - Boost include file not found

Tags: qt, qt-creator, header-files, include-path

I'm using Qt Creator 4.0.3.
I have set Boost header files root path in my Qt project file (.pro) like this:

INCLUDEPATH += C:/devel/boost/1_66_0_msvc2015/include

But I get this compilation error:
C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/variant.hpp': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Solved by launching "qmake" before compiling...